# Amount of memory to allocate to array of strings?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management

I have a char** which is designed to hold and **unknown** amount of strings with **unknown** length

I've initially allocated 10 bytes using

```
char **array = malloc(10);
```

and similarly, before adding strings to this array, I allocate

```
array[num] = malloc(strlen(source)+1)
```

I've noticed that my program crashes upon adding the 6th element to the array

My question is, how does memory with these arrays work? When I allocated 20 bytes, nothing happened, yet when I allocated 30, it suddenly could hold 10 elements. These were all strings of 2-3 characters in size. I'm struggling to think of a condition to realloc memory with, e.g

```
if condition{
    memoryofarray += x amount
    realloc(array, memoryofarray)
}
```

What exactly uses the memory in the char**? I was under the impression that each byte corresponds to how many lines they can hold, i.e. malloc(10) would allow the array to hold 10 strings. I need to know this to establish conditions + to know how much to increment the memory allocated to the array by.

Also, curiously, when I malloced

```
array[num] = malloc(0)
```

before assigning a string to that array element, it worked without problems. Don't you need to at least have strlen amount of bytes to store strings? This is confusing me massively

Comment: `char  **` is **not** and array!

Comment: You have a bug somewhere. Find that and then see if there are any questions/misconceptions remaining.

Comment: `a char **` is not, by any means, an array

Comment: Remember that `malloc` allocates a number of *bytes* not a number of elements. So doing e.g. `char **array = malloc(10)` will only allocate 10 *bytes* and not 10 pointers to `char *`.

Comment: Are sure you intend to allocate ten bytes for `char*`s? Ten bytes arent't a multiple of any pointer size on any machine I know of.

Comment: You sound confused indeed. Could you provide some more specific code? For instance, how do you use the realloc? Is the string you want to store zero-bounded? How do you copy it? (If possible, clear the code out of non-relevant parts).

Comment: I've been using strcpy(array[num],source) and it works - the strings are stored as a dict and I can access them using array[num], so why isn't it an array of strings? Genuine question, I'm a beginner at C.

Comment: correct this: `char **array = malloc(10);` to this: `char **array = malloc(10 * sizeof( char *));`  then use `realloc()` when need more than 10 strings.  for each `char *` entry in the 'array[]', call malloc() with the actual length+1 of the specific string, then copy the specific string into the array[][]  by: `strcpy( &array[x][0], ptrSourceString );

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
char **array = malloc(10);
```

allocates 10 bytes, however, remember that a pointer is not the same size as a byte.

Therefore you need to make sure you allocate an array of sufficient size by using the size of the related type:

```
char **array = malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));
```

Now that you have an array of 10 **pointers** you need to allocate memory for each of the 10 strings, e.g.

```
array[0] = malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
```

Here `sizeof(char)` is not needed but I added it to make it more obvious how malloc works.

Answer (score 2):

1. This will allocate enough memory for 10 pointers to char (`char*`) in array

   ```
   char **array = malloc(10*sizeof(array[0]));
   ```

   On a `64bit` system the size of a `char*` is 8 bytes = 64 bits. The size of a `char` is typically 1 byte = 8 bits.
2. The advantage of using `sizeof(array[0])` instead `sizeof(char*)` is that it's easier to change the type of `array` in the future.
3. `char**` is pointer to a pointer to `char`. It may point to the start of a memory block in the heap with pointers to `char`. Similarly `char*` is a pointer to `char` and it may point to the start of a memory block of `char` on the heap.
4. If you write beyond the allocated memory you get undefined behaviour. If you are lucky it may actually behave well! So when you do for example :

   ```
   array[num] = malloc(0);
   ```

   you may randomly not get a segmentation fault out of (good) luck.
5. Your use of `realloc` is wrong. `realloc` may have to move the memory block whose size you want to increase in which case it will return a new pointer. Use it like this :

   ```
   if (condition) {
       memoryofarray += amount;
       array = realloc(array, memoryofarray);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hold `10` strings then you need to allocate memory for `10` `char *`'s and *then allocate memory to those `char` pointers* .You allocate memory of `10` bytes( *not enough for* `10` `char *`'s ) .Allocate like this -

```
char **array = malloc(10*sizeof(char *));   // allocate memory for 10 char *'s
```

And then do what you were doing -

```
array[num] = malloc(strlen(source)+1)    // allocate desired memory to each pointer
```

*note* - take care that `num` is initialized and does not access out of bound index.

Comment: This give room for 10 **pointers** to a "string", not for a "string" itself.

Comment: @alk  OP allocates to them himself correctly as mentioned in question (not a problem though) . This is the part in which he has problem.

Comment: Size of char*? would that just be 10*sizeof(array)?

Comment: @RobertBenedict  That will be equal to `sizeof array[0]` . `array` is of type `char **` .

Answer (score 1):

Rather than allocating memory using the fault-prone style

```
pointer = malloc(n); // or 
pointer = malloc(n * sizeof(type_of_pointer));
```

Use

```
pointer = malloc(sizeof *pointer * n);
```

Then

```
// Bad: certainly fails to allocate memory for 10 `char *` pointers
// char **array = malloc(10);

// Good
char **array = malloc(sizeof *array * 10);
```

> how does memory with these arrays work?

If insufficient memory is allocated, it does not work.  So step 1: allocate sufficient memory.

Concerning `array[num] = malloc(0)`.  An allocation of 0 may return `NULL` or a pointer to no writable memory or a pointer to *some* writable memory.  Writing to that pointer memory is **undefined behavior (UB)** in any of the 3 cases.  Code may crash, may "work", it is simply UB.  Code must not attempt writing to that pointer.

To be clear: "worked without problems" does not mean code is correct.  C is coding without a net.  Should code do something wrong (UB), the language is not obliged to catch that error.  So follow safe programming practices.

Answer (score 0):

First allocate an array of pointers:

```
char* (*array)[n] = malloc( sizeof(*array) );
```

Then for each item in the array, allocate the variable-length strings individually:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  (*array)[i] = malloc( some_string_length );
}
```

Comment: Suggest `some_string_length` -> `some_string_length + 1`.